# Play sound file in Ubuntu with system() function

Tags: c++, ubuntu, audio

I try to play sound file using C++ in Ubuntu. I can compile this code in terminal with `g++ play.cpp -o play` line. It can be compiled well, but when I execute it with `./play` , it says `Failed to play sound: File or data corrupt` . I cannot find where is the problem. Here is my code;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  system("canberra-gtk-play -f cow.wav");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you execute `canberra-gtk-play -f cow.wav` instead of `./play`?

Comment: @immibis it still gives the same error

Comment: Well then clearly the error has nothing to do with your C program.

Comment: check this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253074/how-to-play-or-open-mp3-or-wav-sound-file-in-c-program"

Comment: Did you install canberra-gtk-play?

Comment: @duong_dajgja if this is correct, I write `sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module` in terminal

Answer (score 2):

The output `Failed to play sound: File or data corrupt` comes from the canberra player launched by your system call and is not a consequence to a problem in your program.

This could mean that this specific file is indeed corrupt. I suggest to download a different example file. The files provided [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Sound_Examples.html) are playing fine for me.

Using 'exiftool cow.wav' might give you more information on what the problem with the file is.