# #pragma comment( lib, "Winmm.lib" ) Not working

Tags: c++, playsound

I am trying to use PlaySound and I put

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "Winmm.lib" )
using namespace std;

int main()
{

PlaySound(L"C:\\Users\\iD Student\\Downloads\\HarryPotter.mp3", 0, SND_FILENAME);

}
```

and instead of playing the sound I wanted it to, it played some default Windows sound.

Comment: Are you sure that's the way to play a sound? You don't actually [call the function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in this code.

Comment: This is what I am putting at the top of my code. The actual code is a PlaySound line

Comment: Please, post the *actual code* then by editing your question.

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to this

Comment: It's okay to be new. Just take a little time to read over your question and make sure you've provided all the relevant information that can help someone else understand and/or reproduce your problem.

Comment: Got it. I'll make sure to do that.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but I think `PlaySound` is limited to `.wav` type files, so you may need [another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253074/how-to-play-or-open-mp3-or-wav-sound-file-in-c-program) for MP3 files.

Comment: Awesome! It worked. Thank you so much!!

Comment: If you have a working line of code, it's probably worth adding that as a self-answer since it could help others.

Comment: Someone asked a similar question this week. PlaySound does not support mp3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PlaySound does not support .mp3 files. It only supports .wav files.

This is the simple code for playing sounds:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "Winmm.lib" )
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//Replace C:\\Users\\iD Student\\Downloads\\HarryPotter.wav with the location of your file
PlaySound(L"C:\\Users\\iD Student\\Downloads\\HarryPotter.wav", 0, SND_FILENAME);

}
```